# suggestion on how to solve an infinte loop problem (python-pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, infinite-loop

I have a data frame with 384 rows (and an additional dummy one in the bigining).
each row has 4 variable I wrote manually. 3 calculated fields based on those 4 variables.
and 3 that are comparing each calculated variable to the row before. each field can have 1 of two values (basically True/False).

Final goal - I want to arrange the data frame in a way that the 64 possible combination of the 6 calculated fields (2^6), occur 6 times (2^6*6=384).
Each iteration does a frequency table (pivot) and if one of the fields differ from 6 it breaks and randomize the order.

The problem that there are 384!-12*6! possible combinations and my computer is running the following script for over 4 days without a solution.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

# a function that calculates if a row is congruent or in-congruent
def set_cong(df):
    if df["left"] > df["right"] and df["left_size"] > df["right_size"] or df["left"] < df["right"] and df["left_size"] < df["right_size"]:
         return "Cong"
    else:
         return "InC"

# open file and calculate the basic fields
DF = pd.read_csv("generator.csv")
DF["distance"] = abs(DF.right-DF.left)
DF["CR"] = DF.left > DF.right
DF["Cong"] = DF.apply(set_cong, axis=1)
again = 1

# main loop to try and find optimal order
while again == 1:
    # make a copy of the DF to not have to load it each iteration
    df = DF.copy()
    again = 0
    df["rand"] = [[random.randint(low=1, high=100000)] for i in range(df.shape[0])]
    # as 3 of the fields are calculated based on the previous row the first one is a dummy and when sorted needs to stay first
    df.rand.loc[0] = 0
    Sorted = df.sort_values(['rand'])

    Sorted["Cong_n1"] = Sorted.Cong.eq(Sorted.Cong.shift())
    Sorted["Side_n1"] = Sorted.CR.eq(Sorted.CR.shift())
    Sorted["Dist_n1"] = Sorted.distance.eq(Sorted.distance.shift())
    # here the dummy is deleted
    Sorted = Sorted.drop(0, axis=0)
    grouped = Sorted.groupby(['distance', 'CR', 'Cong', 'Cong_n1', 'Dist_n1', "Side_n1"])

    for name, group in grouped:
        if group.shape[0] != 6:
            again = 1
            break

Sorted.to_csv("Edos.csv", sep="\t",index=False)
print ("bye")
```

the data frame looks like this:

```
left right size_left size_right distance cong CR distance_n1 cong_n1 side_n1

  1    6      22         44        5      T    F   dummy       dummy   dummy

  5    4      44         22        1      T    T     F           T       F

  2    3      44         22        1      F    F     T           F       F
```

Comment: You want to list all 384! combinations. You realize this is quite impossible?

Comment: Do you realize how big 384! is? 384! is ~2 followed by 827 zeros

Comment: A deck of cards has 52! combinations and there' s a lot of representations of how big that number is. [This is just one](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/1x4mw3/just_how_many_possible_card_combinations_are_there/). Just 52! has 67 zeroes, so 384! is plainly an absurd number. Your computer could be running that script for centuries and probably never finish

Comment: what a 384! combinations , I can't even think of the number of potentials, its basically 384x383x382....x1, the loop surelly will loop forever

Comment: Here's a hint: If the number itself is 200 characters too long to fit into a comment box, maybe rethink your approach

Comment: I don't wont all combinations, I want 1 that works. I tried removing 2 variables (distance_n1, side_n1 - frequency updated to 24 instead of 6) and after about 309,00 iteration it found a solution. But there is a limit to brute force... any ideas how to get to a solution on a different way?